# Cordova Socket io xhr poll error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, sockets, socket.io

i am having trouble making a connection between socket.io server and socket.io client in apache cordova application. It just won't connect to server which i run in node.js.

My socket.io server code is as follows:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
    });

    socket.emit('text', 'wow. such event. very real time.');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

My cordova js code is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Hello from app 1234");
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});
    console.log("socket created");
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log("Connection created!");
        alert("connection ok");
        socket.on('text', function(text) {
            alert(text);
        });
    });
}
```

When i execute it locally in my browser with cordova serve, it runs fine.
Also it's fine when i'm doing a regular XMLHttpRequest() to any server, i tested it and was able to receive JSON just fine.

Errors:

```
"socket.io-client:manager connect_error +49ms"
"engine.io-client:socket socket error %j +50ms",Error: xhr poll error
"socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after %d     +113ms",20000
"engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +5s"
"engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data %s +1ms",null
"engine.io-client:socket setting transport %s +110ms","polling"
"engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open %s: %s +28ms","GET","http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1481551911376-8"
```

What could be my issue and how could i debug it further?

EDIT: I am testing it on emulator with `cordova emulate android`

Comment: So your are testing from a real device?

Comment: @Beat Edited, i am testing it on emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `localhost` on a real `device` or even on an `emulator`, always refers to the `ip` of the device or emulator itself. This is also explains, why it is working in your `browser` with `cordova serve`.

Instead of using `localhost` you have to use the local ip of your computer. You can get it for example from windows command promt (e.g. `cmd.exe`) by using `ipconfig`.